# How can I retrieve the value from an enum?

Tags: ios, swift, enums, swiftystorekit

I'm using `SwiftyStoreKit` and figuring out how to retrieve the status of receipt validation. I would like to retrieve `status` from `receiptInvalid(receipt: ["status": 21004, "environment": Sandbox], status: SwiftyStoreKit.ReceiptStatus.secretNotMatching)`. How would I get the value **21004**?

`receiptInvalid` is a a result of the last case:

```
public enum ReceiptError: Swift.Error {
// No receipt data
case noReceiptData
// No data received
case noRemoteData
// Error when encoding HTTP body into JSON
case requestBodyEncodeError(error: Swift.Error)
// Error when proceeding request
case networkError(error: Swift.Error)
// Error when decoding response
case jsonDecodeError(string: String?)
// Receive invalid - bad status returned
case receiptInvalid(receipt: ReceiptInfo, status: ReceiptStatus)
}
```

ReceiptInfo:

```
public typealias ReceiptInfo = [String: AnyObject]
```

End goal is to test for code **21007** for Apple App Review. Thanks!

Edit: What code goes where the comment is?

```
case .error(let error):
            print("Receipt verification failed: \(error)")
            //error prints receiptInvalid(receipt: ["status": 21004, "environment": Sandbox], status: SwiftyStoreKit.ReceiptStatus.secretNotMatching)
            if case .receiptInvalid = error {
                //What goes here?
            }
```

Comment: Please do not edit your question to include the solution. That's what answers are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend enumerations with handy computed variables for accessing associated values:

```
 extension ReceiptError {
   var invalidReceipt: (receipt: ReceiptInfo, status: RecriptStatus)? {
       switch self {
       case .receiptInvalid(let receipt, let status):
           return (receipt: receipt, status: status)
       default:
           return nil
       }
   }
}

print(someReceiptError.invalidReceipt.receipt["status"
```

Comment: Would I be able to use this with my edit? For example, how would I use this where the comment is in my edit? I'm still new at this, sorry.

Comment: Oh, you already have a pattern matching against `receiptInvalid`. All you have to do is add the `(let receipt, let status)` pattern in the pattern, just as I did.